# Not able to set index.mapping.single_type: true on an index

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, elasticsearch-mapping

I had an index that had single type. Now, I am planning to enable "index.mapping.single_type" and I triggered the following API to make it happen, got the following error.

BTW, I closed the index before applying the above API.

Is there a problem with the syntax or is it not allowed .

```
PUT testindex1/_settings
{
"settings": {
"index.mapping.single_type": true
}
}

{
"error": {
"root_cause": [
{
"type": "illegal_argument_exception",
"reason": "final testindex1 setting [index.mapping.single_type], not updateable"
}
],
"type": "illegal_argument_exception",
"reason": "final testindex1 setting [index.mapping.single_type], not updateable"
},
"status": 400
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some settings are not updatable dynamically even when the index is closed, `index.number_of_shards` is also one such setting and they are called `final` settings and your `index.mapping.single_type` is also `final` setting, which is mentioned even in your error message, I bolded the `final` part of setting to distinguish it.

> **final** testindex1 setting [index.mapping.single_type], not updateable

you can better understand it using the Elasticsearch source code. class `org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Setting` defines the type of settings and see the below explanation for `final` settings.

> /**
>            * mark this setting as final, not updateable even when the context is not dynamic
>            * ie. **Setting this property on an index scoped setting will fail update when the index is closed**
>            */
>           Final,

You can check [this line](https://github.com/amitmbm/elasticsearch/blob/master/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/common/settings/Setting.java#L104https://github.com/amitmbm/elasticsearch/blob/master/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/common/settings/Setting.java#L104) for the above code in Elasticsearch, which explains more and the below code shows this `final` type is used to create `number of primary shard` settings.

```
Setting.intSetting(SETTING_NUMBER_OF_SHARDS, 1, 1, maxNumShards, Property.IndexScope, Property.Final);
```

I hope you understand, now the reason for the error and it looks like you have to re-index the data which new setting.

Comment: hmm, is there any way to enforce this in 5.6 and how if there is a way ? As I understand it is index level setting, either it can be applied as part of index creation or after index created ?

Comment: @Nag, yeah but look at the Elasticsearch code, it seems it's not possible to change the final settings at all, and for `index.number_of_shards` there is even integration tests in the elastic code base to through different error, when the index is closed and when the index is open ..

Comment: @Nag, you will hv to create a new index with new value of this index.

Comment: hmm, i tried with new index as you see above, it is even failing as part of index creation. It doesn't seem it works in any way irrespective of whether index is the new or old  [ in 5.6 ]

Comment: aplogies , if i wasted ur time - come across something in documentation - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/removal-of-types.htmlElasticsearch 5.6.0
Setting index.mapping.single_type: true on an index will enable the single-type-per-index behaviour which will be enforced in 6.0.

Comment: @Nag, yes this property is very much relevant in 5.6, it's enforced in 6.0 , deprecated in 7.x and will be removed in 8.X. I.e. this is step by step in all these major versions to remove the `types` in index

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210728/discussion-between-opster-elasticsearch-ninja-and-nag).